# Handle table xpath/3

Tags: prolog

I have noticed that if i use xpath(DOM, //table(N), T), the system extracts only the external tables, but if i have a table into another table, i can see it only i use findall/3. The predicate findall/3 extract all table, but i can't access to internal table. Why?

I use

```
xpath(DOM, //table(N), T)
```

to extract the N-th table, but the system extracts only external table. If i have for example:

```
<table>
    <table>
    </table>
<table>
```

i can't use xpath(DOM, //table(N), T), because i would have only one table. If I insert //table(2), the system fails. Instead, if i use findall/3 i have all table in the DOM, but with findall i haven't access to the n-th table. How can i do?

Answer (score 1):

indexing works 'on levels', to access nested elements you can specify the path, or - if the path is only partially known - use multiple xpath calls.

test data (way too simple)

```
?- D=element(table,[id=one],[element(table,[id=two],[])]).
```

raw search operator indexed:

```
?- xpath($D, //table(N), T).
N = last,
T = element(table, [id=one], [element(table, [id=two], [])]) ;
N = last,
T = element(table, [id=two], []) ;
false.
```

fully known path

```
?- xpath($D, //table/table(@id), ID).
ID = two ;
false.
```

multiple xpath 'joined' (this is most flexible, but the behaviour of search operators need some apprenticeship...)

```
?- xpath($D, //table, T), xpath(T, table(@id), ID).
T = element(table, [id=one], [element(table, [id=two], [])]),
ID = two ;
false.
```